# How to extract specific key value pairs from a grep output

Tags: linux, awk, command-line, grep, cut

I have the output of grep in a folder as below,

```
./Data1/TEST_Data1.xml:<def-query collection="FT_R1Event" count="-1" desc="" durationEnd="1" durationStart="0" durationType="CAL" fromWS="Data1" id="_q1" timeUnit="D">

./Data2/TEST_Data2.xml:<def-query collection="FT_R2Event" count="-1" desc="" durationEnd="2" durationStart="0" durationType="ABS" fromWS="Data2" id="_q1" timeUnit="M">
```

I want to extract the below followed by some delimiter, say ',' as below,

```
Data1/TEST_Data1, durationEnd="1", timeUnit="D"

Data2/TEST_Data2, durationEnd="2", timeUnit="M"
```

Please help me in achieveing this using the basic linux commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it using GNU `AWK` following way. Let `file.txt` content be

```
./Data1/TEST_Data1.xml:<def-query collection="FT_R1Event" count="-1" desc="" durationEnd="1" durationStart="0" durationType="CAL" fromWS="Data1" id="_q1" timeUnit="D">

./Data2/TEST_Data2.xml:<def-query collection="FT_R2Event" count="-1" desc="" durationEnd="2" durationStart="0" durationType="ABS" fromWS="Data2" id="_q1" timeUnit="M">
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=", ";FPAT="(^[^ ]+xml)|((durationEnd|timeUnit)=\"[^\"]+\")"}{gsub(/\.([/]|xml)/, "", $1);print}' file.txt
```

output

```
Data1/TEST_Data1, durationEnd="1", timeUnit="D"

Data2/TEST_Data2, durationEnd="2", timeUnit="M"
```

Explanation: I used `FPAT` to extract interesting elements of input, namely these which from start does not contain spaces and are following by `xml` or ((`durationEnd` or `timeUnit`) followed by `"` non-`"` `"`). Then I remove `.` followed by `/` or `xml` (note that `.` has to be literal `.` so it is escaped). Then I print everything, which is joined by `,`  as I set it as output field seperator (`OFS`).

Disclaimer: I tested it only with shown samples.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*